# How do I call this Delphi method in C# using Dllimport?

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, dllimport

New Programmer in need of Help!

The Delphi code that is compiled into the DLL

```pascal
function SetCurrentSerial(Size : Integer; Msg : Pointer) : Integer stdcall;
var
  TempByte : PByte;
  TempStr : string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  TempByte := Msg;
  TempStr := '';
  for i := 0 to Size - 1 do
  begin
    TempStr := TempStr + ' ';
  end;

  for i := 0 to Size - 1 do
  begin
    TempStr[i+1] := Chr(TempByte^);
    Inc(TempByte);
  end;

  if not DLLClass.SelectDeviceSerial(TempStr) then
  begin
    Result := -1;
  end;
end;
```

The C# Code

```cs
//Import a Function Pointer
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention= CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet =  CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe static extern int SetCurrentSerial(int Size, byte[] Msg);
```

I need to store the pointer value, Size and Msg in a buffer and print the value in a console window.

I will greatly appreciate a fully constructed code. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I've so far tried.
//C# Code

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("Test.dll")]
    public unsafe static extern int SetCurrentSerial(int Size, void* Msg); 

    unsafe static void Main()
     {
        int Res;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        Res = SetCurrentSerial(255, &buffer);

        Console.WriteLine("%s\n", buffer);
     }
}
```

Comment: Is your Delphi function exported?

Comment: @Jerry The delphi function is stored in the dll named "Test.dll" I was to import it function in c#, I need to build a GUI that will  communicate between the USB Device via the dll.

Comment: But did you explicitly export it? And as Bernd says, why isn't it working?

Comment: @Bernd Yes i've tried a few codes, i'm getting errors, that talk about unmanaged type .....

Comment: We need your exact error message, and part of your question, not later in the comments.

Comment: I'm having problem with the pointer and to  reference it.

Comment: What about your previous question. Please can we finish that one. What did you ignore my advice about `unsafe`?

Comment: How is this different from the other question ? Prototypes matches in parameters. Just the meaning of the buffer is different. Once is input, once output.

Comment: @TLama Well, input and output is the difference. Makes a difference in how you call it. It would have been nice if asker could have got on top of the first question. Then the second one would likely not have been needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DLL function is designed incorrectly. You are passing a string from the calling code to the DLL. That is really simple to do and you can remove almost all of your code. The Delphi code should be like this:

```
function SetCurrentSerial(Serial: PAnsiChar): LongBool; stdcall;
begin
  Result := DLLClass.SelectDeviceSerial(Serial);
end;
```

Then the C# code should be:

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool SetCurrentSerial(string Serial);
```

Call the function like this:

```
bool succeeded = SetCurrentSerial(Serial);
if (!succeeded)
{
    // handle error
}
```

I've replaced your integer return value with a boolean indicating success or failure. Should you prefer to revert to an integer that would look like this:

**Delphi**

```
function SetCurrentSerial(Serial: PAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  if DLLClass.SelectDeviceSerial(Serial) then begin
    Result := 0;
  end else begin
    Result := -1;
  end;
end;
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int SetCurrentSerial(string Serial);
```

---

**Update**

Apparently you cannot change this DLL. That is a shame because it is really very badly designed and implemented. However, to call that function from C# you need to declare the p/invoke like this:

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int SetCurrentSerial(int Size, byte[] Msg);
```

And then call it like this:

```
byte[] Msg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(serial);
int retval = SetCurrentSerial(Msg.Length, Msg);
if (retval != 0)
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thank you @David for your Help, I'm going home now will try to implement this codes, and the previous one and will get back to you later.

Comment: the Delphi code is stored in a dll it can not be changed, and its work fine with GUI design with Boland, I want to build GUIs with Visual C#, its kinda divorcing with delphi, but I need the dll and all its functions to be imported into C#.

Comment: Whoever wrote that DLL did not know what they were doing. It's really badly done. So be it. I've added an example call to that poorly written function.

Comment: @ David Heffernan, Where does the argument (serial) come from, its does not exist in the current context. The call definition will not build.

Comment: It's a string that you supply

Comment: This suggests to me, together with the calling code in your question, that you don't yet understand what the function `SetCurrentSerial` does. I note that your calling code does not provide a serial string. The function you are calling receives as an input parameter a string that specifies the serial. The DLL function then, albeit inefficiently, re-constructs the string to pass to SelectDeviceSerial.

Comment: The Function set the serial number of the device currently connected, meaning if my device is connected i should be able to get its serial displayed on my console window.

Comment: No. That's not what the function does. It receives an input parameter as I said. The function in your other question returns a string. The function here though is a setter.

Comment: my main problem is to pass the address of the buffer to the function, I have many functions that will use the same calling definition.Check this code : byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; void* buff; buff = buffer;

Comment: how do i pass the void* buff; address to buff=buffer; i'm getting an error that says cannot  implicitly convert type byte[] to void*

Comment: You aren't listening to me. Don't use unsafe. Do it the way I show in the answer. There's no point in me continuing trying to help you if you ignore me. Why would I spend my time arguing with you and repeating myself? As you say yourself, you are a novice. If you do want to learn I can help, but you have to listen.

Comment: I'm listening to ur suggestion, but when i remove unsafe, i get Error: Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Comment: Use the code in my answer. My p/invoke declaration does not use pointers. Or fixed buffers.

Comment: How do I fix the Error (serial) The name serial does not exist in the current context

Comment: `string serial = "your serial goes here";`

Comment: With respect, you need to step back a bit and try to understand what the function you are calling actually does. You seem to think that it will return you a string. It won't. It receives a string as input and returns an integer indicating success or failure. And you really do need to master the C# language a little more before you start doing interop. I think you are attempting to run before you can walk.

Comment: Ah ah, that's a learning process, isn't it, the input that it is supposed to receive is the USB HID device, so my code need to detect it.

Comment: There's not much more to add to my answer. It is the answer to the question you asked. You asked how to call that function from C#.

Comment: I cannot input the serial number, the dll, is doing that for me, its all defined in the dll, the delphi function i posted here is just piece of a long program. so all i need is the communication with the dll.

Comment: I understand, and i appreciate your help, I will accept the answer and will figure out the implementation.

Comment: OK. Thanks. What you need to do next is get a better understanding of what this DLL does and which functions you need to call.