# How to call a Delphi method from .NET using a VisualPlugin?

Tags: c#, delphi

I have created a new window base class which is called when a WPF window is opened. 
In this base class a Delphi method should be called.

Interface: .NET:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RemObjects.Hydra.CrossPlatform;

namespace MyNameSpace.CrossPlatform
{
[Guid("11111111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777"), ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICrossPlatformInterface : IHYCrossPlatformInterface
{
   void MyMethodToCall(string windowName);
}
```

Delphi:

```
ICrossPlatformInterface = interface(IHYCrossPlatformInterface)
['{11111111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777}']
  procedure MyMethodToCall(const windowName: WideString); safecall;
end;
```

The plugin looks like this:

```
[Plugin, VisualPlugin, ComVisible(true)]
public partial class Plugin : VisualPlugin, IHYCrossPlatformInterface, ICrossPlatformInterface 
{
   ...
   public void EntryPointCalledFromWinBaseClass(string windowName)
   {
      // What to do?
   }
```

Delphi:

```
type
TCrossPlatformFactory = class(THYFakeIDispatch, ICrossPlatformInterface)
public
   procedure MyMethodToCall(const WindowName: WideString); safecall;
end;
```

How can I call the call this Delphi method?

Comment: from the `C# Code you need to call / use the DllImport call something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976983/how-do-i-call-this-delphi-method-in-c-sharp-using-dllimport

Comment: I have to use Hydra...

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Can't you just call the method?

Comment: No I can't. I am creating an instance of my plugin in c#.
'var plugin = Plugin.Instance;' Than I tried to use a delegate to call the delhpi function. But it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution was to create first an instance in Delphi of the class which contains the function I want to call from .NET.

```
FCrossPlatformFactory := TCrossPlatformFactory.Create;
```

Than I have to call a .NET function and pass the instance as an argument.

```
Factory.SetCrossPlatformFactory(FCrossPlatformFactory);
```

.NET:

```
public static ICrossPlatformInterface CrossPlatformFactory
{
    get { return Factory._getCrossPlatformFactory; }
    set { Factory._getCrossPlatformFactory = value; }
}

public void SetCrossPlatformFactory(ICrossPlatformInterface crossPlatformFactory)
{
    CrossPlatformFactory = crossPlatformFactory;
}
```

Once the instance is known in .NET the function can be called.

```
Factory.CrossPlatformFactory.MyMethodToCall(windowName);
```